# ReactJS Converting into class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to convert this code from https://codepen.io/mozmorris/pen/yLYKzyp?editors=0010:

```
const WebcamStreamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const mediaRecorderRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [capturing, setCapturing] = React.useState(false);
  const [recordedChunks, setRecordedChunks] = React.useState([]);

  const handleStartCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCapturing(true);
    mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(webcamRef.current.stream, {
      mimeType: "video/webm"
    });
    mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener(
      "dataavailable",
      handleDataAvailable
    );
    mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
  }, [webcamRef, setCapturing, mediaRecorderRef]);

  const handleDataAvailable = React.useCallback(
    ({ data }) => {
      if (data.size > 0) {
        setRecordedChunks((prev) => prev.concat(data));
      }
    },
    [setRecordedChunks]
  );

  const handleStopCaptureClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    setCapturing(false);
  }, [mediaRecorderRef, webcamRef, setCapturing]);

  const handleDownload = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (recordedChunks.length) {
      const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
        type: "video/webm"
      });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = "display: none";
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "react-webcam-stream-capture.webm";
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      setRecordedChunks([]);
    }
  }, [recordedChunks]);

  return (
    <>
      <Webcam audio={false} ref={webcamRef} />
      {capturing ? (
        <button onClick={handleStopCaptureClick}>Stop Capture</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleStartCaptureClick}>Start Capture</button>
      )}
      {recordedChunks.length > 0 && (
        <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<WebcamStreamCapture />, document.getElementById("root"));

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam
```

Into something more like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {Alert} from "reactstrap";

export default class InlineAlert extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.handleDismiss = this.handleDismiss.bind(this)
  }

  handleDismiss() {
    this.props.dismissed()
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.message) {
      if (this.props.timer || this.props.timer > 0)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.handleDismiss()
        }, this.props.timer*1000);
      return (
        <Alert color={this.props.bsStyle} toggle={this.handleDismiss}>
              <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}></span>
        </Alert>
      );
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

Any guidance? I've been struggling for way too long..

Would like to create this standalone component so it can be called any time from the parent component to process the video/data

Comment: Is the second snippet *just* an example of a class-based component? Or is it related to the first? I'm not sure why you'd want to convert a functional component to a class-based one, but please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Literally I just picked up ReactJS from a 2 year hiatus and need to figure out how to convert it, or use it in my older structure..

Comment: Hooks doesn't work in classes, and your function based component has a lot of hooks, useRefs and useCallback, so you would need to implement these the "old way". Not sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: Well, just about everything React from 2-ish years ago is still compatible with current React. It would probably be better to update your version of React and tweak anything that *might* break than it would be to try and rewrite a *current* module use an outdated class-based component syntax.